# Python Selenium : Scrolling google reviews to add more reviews on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Google reviews has 10 reviews on the page, as you scroll to end, more reviews get added

I want to scrape close to 100 reviews, but scrolling using python gets me to the end of the page but doesn't add more reviews. I've tried this on chrome & firefox.

I can scroll to the bottom using this -
`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

I tried going "below the bottom" to add more reviews -
`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight+100000);")`

So far neither has worked

Here's the url I'm using- https://www.google.com/travel/hotels/google%20reviews%20jw%20marriott%20washington%20dc/entity/CgoIgo6ywKe90tx5EAE/reviews?q=google%20reviews%20jw%20marriott%20washington%20dc&g2lb=2502548%2C2503771%2C2503781%2C4258168%2C4270442%2C4284970%2C4291517%2C4306835%2C4597339%2C4718358%2C4723331%2C4731329%2C4757164%2C4778035%2C4814050%2C4861688%2C4864715%2C4874190%2C4879519%2C4886082%2C4886480%2C4893075%2C4902277%2C4905351%2C4905600%2C4906050%2C4920622%2C4926165%2C4926489%2C4931265&hl=en-IN&gl=in&ssta=1&rp=EIKOssCnvdLceRCCjrLAp73S3Hk4AkAASAHAAQI&ictx=1&sa=X&ved=0CAAQ5JsGahcKEwj4i9rCzM78AhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQBA&utm_campaign=sharing&utm_medium=link&utm_source=htls&ts=CAESABpJCisSJzIlMHg4OWI3Yjc5NzljZGQ4YmUzOjB4NzliOTQ5ZWE3ODBjODcwMhoAEhoSFAoHCOcPEAIYBhIHCOcPEAIYBxgBMgIQACoJCgU6A0lOUhoA

Answer (score 0):

You should try not to go to the very bottom of the page but a little over it so that the page loads what is underneath. For example you could scroll down little by little:

```
height = 0
while True:#or some other condition
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, "+str(height) +");")
    sleep(2)
    height = height + 100
```

It is slow but you should let some time to 'sleep' to allow the page to load.